# how to change UISlder from horizontal to vertical in Xamarin's monotouch?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, uislider

I need my UISlider, in a Monotouch iPad app, to be vertical, not horizontal.
How is this done in Monotouch?

For iOS, the solution elsewhere on Stackoverflow is this in iOS:

```c
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    CGAffineTransform trans = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI * 0.5);
    slider.transform = trans;
}
```

So, in my monotouch .cs C# file I did this:

```cs
using MonoTouch.CoreGraphics;
public override void ViewDidLoad()
{
    //...
    CGAffineTransform trans = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI * 0.5);
    power_slider.transform = trans;
}
```

...but the Xamarin compiler does not know `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation` and this is not in the Xamarin.iOS API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution that works great:

using System;
using MonoTouch.Foundation;
using MonoTouch.UIKit;
using MonoTouch.CoreGraphics;

CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransform.MakeRotation((float)(Math.PI * 1.5));
ultrasound_power_slider.Transform = transform;
ultrasound_gain_slider.Transform = transform;

Answer (score 0):

`CGAffineTransform.MakeRotation` is defined in `MonoTouch.CoreGraphics`.

So adding

```cs
using MonoTouch.CoreGraphics;
```

will make your code compile.

- Hint 1: the class name starts with `CG`, which is shorthand for `CoreGraphics`.
- Hint 2: in Xamarin.Studio, if you know a type but not where it's defined, type it, then `ctrl-alt-space`. It'll broaden the search base to all referenced assemblies (vs the assemblies listed in `using` directives)

Comment: Monotouch does not recognise CGAffineTransformMakeRotation. And it's not in the Xamarin web iOS API search either...  AH, HAH: the syntax is CGAffineTransform.MakeRotation() !!